# Ask required command-line input in Rails-Generator/Thor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thor

I am building a generator in Ruby-on-Rails and was wondering if it's possible to ask for a required argument with [Thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor). Or if there's a decent workaround. Right now I'm just raising an exception:

```
@foo = ask('[Required] Enter Foo:')
raise 'Required argument missing' unless (@foo).present?
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be:

```
loop do
  @foo = ask('[Required] Enter Foo:')
  break if @foo.present?
end
```